# Algorithm Analysis, Time Complexity of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time, asymptotic-complexity

```
m=1;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    m=m*2;
    for(j=1;j<=m;j++){
        do something that is O(1)
    }
}
```

What will be time complexity of the above code ?? Please tell me how to solve these types of problem.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to look at these problems from the inside out.  Removing the `m`, we have:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=2^i;j++){
        do something that is O(1)
    }
}
```

Or:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    O(2^i)
}
```

So overall: `sum_1^n O(2^i)=O(2^(n+1))=O(2^n)`.

Answer (score 4):

Inner loop will iterate 1 time, then 2 times, then ..., then 2^n times. So we have `1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^n = 2^(n + 1) - 1 = O(2^n)` iterations of inner loop.

One iteration of inner loop has constant complexity, so `summed_inner_loop_complexity = O(2^n)`.

Whole complexity is `O(2^n)`.

Comment: No.  You can multiply by `n`, or get the summed inner loop complexity (better), but both means you're over counting.  The answer should be `O(2^n)`.

Comment: I think it should be O(2^n) as Teepeemm has explained.

Answer (score 0):

Formally and methodically, you can use Sigma notation:

[image]